# How can I load templates from an html file into my Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have a bunch of template html files in my Angular app, and it was getting inefficient for distribution. So I checked out [`grunt-angular-combine`](https://github.com/astik/grunt-angular-combine) to put all my templates into one single HTML file. So now it looks like

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modules/home/profile.template.html">
<div id="template-seasons">
    This is empty! But it's the proifle template
</div></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modules/home/score.template.html">
...
```

The trouble is, how can I "import" all of these individual templates into my app so I can refer to them from my `ui-router` states, `ng-includes`s, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Load the result file, Then you can just use it's path in templateUrl in ui-router config.

```
templateUrl: "modules/home/profile.template.html"
```

Or if you neet to use $compile somewhere, use `$templateCache.get("modules/home/profile.template.html")` to get the template.

Comment: `Load the result file`. How?

Comment: By putting result file contents into your main html file. If you want this to be automatically, there is an grunt plugin for it: https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes / (using ajax for loading templates causes delay.)

Comment: There isn't a better way?

Comment: Personally i use a gulp plugin that converts all templates to a js file and i just merge that file with others js files. This is the grunt alternative i think: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templatecache (updated)